# No rhyme nor reason

Tags: knowledge

Can you find what's hidden behind each element of this list, and why they are described in this way ?

*cheeky ancestor continuously capers and counts*

*free falls for greatly adventurous arachnid*

*bragging about girl's animal : baa baa baa*

*baby dangerously balances amid gusts*

*famous fossil farmer characterizes ducks, describes cattle*

*great gassy diamond disappears elusively, essentially dual*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> They all seem to be nursery rhymes, and the words are restricted to starting with a, b, c, d, e, f, g, with the first letters of each word in the line representing the notes for that rhyme.

cheeky ancestor continuously capers and counts

> This Old Man

free falls for greatly adventurous arachnid

> Itsy Bitsy Spider

bragging about girl's animal : baa baa baa

> Thanks to Brandon: Mary Had a Little Lamb

baby dangerously balances amid gusts

> Thanks to Gareth:
>  Rock-a-bye baby

famous fossil farmer characterizes ducks, describes cattle

> Old MacDonald Had a Farm

great gassy diamond disappears elusively, essentially dual

> Twinkle Twinkle, Little Star

Comment: The baby is presumably from "Rock-a-bye baby on the tree top".

Comment: I think you might have #3 wrong, just because of "girl", and the owner of the black sheep is not specifically mentioned to be a girl. Perhaps this is Rot13(Znel unq n yvggyr ynzo)?

Comment: Bah, I even had the correct tune in my head, but for some reason filled in the wrong title.

Comment: Happens to all of us! Nice answer, have an upvote.

Comment: Good job ! The answer is almost correct : missing only the first rhyme.

Comment: Ah, maybe this new update fixes it?

Comment: Yes. Congrats !